# signalR overhead

Tags: timer, signalr

I have a client which updates its position on the server by periodically (each 4 seconds) sending it's new location. I also have a client which tracks the previous mobile, by periodically pollen the server (each 5 seconds) and get the latest location.

Should this communication be carried over SignalR (for sending the latest location) or by using a timer? I say this as SignalR has some overhead which generates larger request sizes which can be very costly.

Thank you,
RYan

Answer (score 11):

## HTTP communication win

Right now, based on what I understand of your description, you're doing multiple update POSTs and then listeners are using polling GET requests. These have the overhead of separate HTTP requests with headers and, if not using keep-alive or exceeding the keep-alive timeout, [re-]establishing a TCP connection.

Using SignalR you will instead be able to, *at bare minimum*, improve the polling GET side of things because SignalR can use *long* polling which will funnel back multiple responses over a single HTTP GET request and do it in "real-time" rather than always having a hard 4sec lag time. From there you can work your way up through Server Sent Events (SSE) to full blown web sockets depending on the client and server capabilities. Any of these approaches should be more efficient than your currently described implementation.

## Request size win

There's only a small "envelope" around each SignalR message. Compared to HTTP headers your browser clients are most certainly having to send with each update POST and polling GET right now I think SignalR will win this easily. Obviously the payload of the message would be the same JSON in either case, so that's a wash.

## Programming model win

Most importantly, I think, using SignalR gives you a programming model that abstracts you from what exact underlying techniques end up being used and presents you with a consistent real-time communication API rather than having to ultimately worry about thunking down to a disconnected request/response model.

Comment: What is the server side overhead of having connections on the server side open waiting for a response?  For example, even users who maybe left their browser tab open to the site and haven't used it in a week.  My understanding(which is limited) is SignalR automatically reopens closed connections.  So this could be a huge number of connections on the server side.  Not trying to be argumentative, just looking for your insight into this.  Thanks :)

Comment: Watch the SignalR talk from build (link below) for some scalability numbers with the latest bits, but it's scalable to hundreds of thousands per machine. Reason it can do this is cause it's all async I/O, so there's no major resources being wasted unless there's something to be communicated. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034